# Grub doesn't recognize Windows 10 partition after a auto-boot repair of Windows

Tags: partitioning, grub, mbr, hard-drive-recovery, dualboot

My PC was unstable and I needed to remove some peripherals. Additionally, I have one SSD (with Debian 9 and Windows 10 - bootloader GRUB) and an HDD (Windows 10). By default, SSD was the first drive inspected by BIOS. In the operation of removing peripherals on trying to get a more stable system (that frequently was freezing before POST), in a strange manner, the windows boot loader (and not GRUB) was directly loaded by BIOS! On this occasion, an auto windows boot repair was called (that means, no question, only a window indicating the progress of the boot repair tool). After this, from the next boot on, the BIOS only calls  GRUB that can't handle with Windows 10 partition.

The Windows 10 partition is accessible. I can mount it and see all of its content. The FStable seems to be intact. I don't understand how the boot process occurs, but yet I believe only the MBR of Windows was damaged and the partition itself can become bootable again. Perhaps, rewriting that MBR (in this case, I have no idea how to do it).

Actually, the HDD is removed. I have tried to use GRUB to call partition (giving the correct new name of partition ( (HD1, MS-DOS) have become (HD0,msdos3) ) but this wasn't sufficient.

What could I do to resolve this problem? A good reference to GRUB and/or partition systems? I'm sure it's possible to recover the functionality of such a partition.

**P.S.:** upgrade-boot doesn't work. It has only removed the old menu entry of Windows (in effective terms).

> fdisk : p

> > /dev/sda1                    2048  77931735  77929688   37,2G 83 Linux

> > /dev/sda2                81922048 286722047 204800000   97,7G  7 HPFS/NTFS
> > /exFAT

> > /dev/sda3   *           286722048 468875263 182153216   86,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS
> > /exFAT

> > /dev/sda4                77932542  81922047   3989506    1,9G  5 Estendida

> > /dev/sda5                77932544  81922047   3989504    1,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: Do you have a Windows 10 install medium (DVD or USB)? If so, boot on it, choose to Repair instead of Install, go Advanced, then Command Line, and enter "bootsect /nt60 all /force", press Enter, and check if you get a positive return, like "all boot sectors have been updated", or something like that (it'll be in your own language if the install medium is in another language but English).

Comment: Can I perform "bootsect /nt60 all /force" from linux? Run a equivalent program, I mean

Comment: The command I suggested can only be performed in a Windows PE (Preinstallation Environment) command line. You can try one of the methods mentioned here (https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-bootloader-linux/) if you want. I'd go with method 2, but that's up to you.